# How does this page detect movement of a desktop browser window?

Tags: javascript, html

In messing around with some DeviceOrientation stuff, I came across [this](https://mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/ball-pool/) page.

When you shake the browser, the site reacts! What API is being used here where the browser movement is detected? I notice it works in the latest versions of Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

I don't see any mention of this in the DeviceOrientation docs, nor on three.js...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the [`window.screenX/screenY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screenX) properties to get browser window position and [`window.innerWidth/innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) to get window's size.

> The Window.screenX read-only property returns the horizontal distance, in CSS pixels, of the left border of the user's browser viewport to the left side of the screen.

The below function is used in that code:

```
function getBrowserDimensions() {

    var changed = false;

    if (stage[0] != window.screenX) {

        delta[0] = (window.screenX - stage[0]) * 50;
        stage[0] = window.screenX;
        changed = true;

    }

    if (stage[1] != window.screenY) {

        delta[1] = (window.screenY - stage[1]) * 50;
        stage[1] = window.screenY;
        changed = true;

    }

    if (stage[2] != window.innerWidth) {

        stage[2] = window.innerWidth;
        changed = true;

    }

    if (stage[3] != window.innerHeight) {

        stage[3] = window.innerHeight;
        changed = true;

    }

    return changed;

}
```

Comment: Note that they have used "deviceorientation" event im 'main.js' on line 53.

Answer (score 0):

use screen.orientation property.
[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation)